# i get confused whit get character from user

Tags: c++, getchar, getch

### I have 2 questions:

Question 1= i search in the internet and i found that everyone told don't use `getch()` or `getche()` in c++. so how can i get a character from user ?? for example i wrote this code so how can i replace getch with another statement ?

Question 2= i wrote this code in visual studio 2013 and it works fine but when i wrote in code block and compile whit GNU GCC compiler getchar() statement doesn't work . why ??

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int word_counter=0,char_counter=0;
char ch;
cout<<"Enter your paragraph and press ENTER for end :\n";
cin>>ch;
while((ch=getchar())!=13)
    char_counter++;
cout<<"Number of characters ="<<char_counter<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What _"doesn't work"_ actually. Edit your question and precisely state what's the problem. Check [MCVE] how to improve your question please.

Comment: Also ask **one** question per question please, otherwise it doesn't fit the intended FAQ like format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: `conio.h` isn't supported by any modern standard C++ compiler, it's just an ancient relict.

Answer (score 1):

First Question:
Use `cin` to get input from the user through the console.

Second Question:
`getchar()` is not supported on GNU gcc compiler as conio is not a part of gcc.`

**EDIT**:

Use `getline()` instead of cin as I earlier mentioned since you want the loop to break only when the input is `'\n'`.

Comment: Probably the OP actually should use `getline()`.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't realize that ASCII 13 meant `\n`. `getline()` is the way to go for this one then. @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 0):

Reponse 1 : `getch()` is  used  to  ask(read)  only  one character  form  the  user(or  file).

Reponse  2:  I  suppose  that you  want  to  count  the  number  of  char.

```
int main() 
{
char c;
long long  n;
do
{
    cin.get(c);
    cout<<c;
    n++;
}while(c!='.'); 
cout<<n<<endl;

return  0;
}
```

Comment: Use proper code formatting please (indent four spaces for code blocks)

Comment: Also no tabs, please!

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1= i search in the internet and i found that everyone told don't use getch() or getche() in c++. so how can i get a character from user ??

Most environments buffer the text before it gets to your program.  You would have to type the text, then press Enter in order to transfer the buffer to your program.

There are no functions nor facilities in standard C++ to get a character from the User as they type it.

You will need to use an OS specific function to fetch a character as the User types it.  You may want to also search the internet for the word "keypress".

> Question 2= i wrote this code in visual studio 2013 and it works fine but when i wrote in code block and compile whit GNU GCC compiler getchar() statement doesn't work . why ??

As others have stated, the `conio.h` file is not standard.

According to [this reference on `getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar), you will need to include `stdio` for the function.

Also note that the C language streams, such as `stdin` and `printf`, may not be compatible with the C++ language streams such as `cout` and `cin`.  They may have different buffers.  Pick one or the other and *don't cross the streams.*